# jQuery UI Sortable position issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using twitter bootstrap responsive/fluid layout with jquery ui sortable.

I'm trying to make the `span1`, `span2` etc sortable both vertically and horizontally, but there seems to be a position problem while sorting is going on.

I have to go now, but I'll elaborate on this, but [here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8C3e/). Just try dragging the columns and you'll see.

Anyone know a way to handle this behavior?

Comment: your jfiddle is not working...

Comment: @sourcecode It works fine here.. what's the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was a bug in my code. The sortable items had unnecessary margins.